# Using Sidekiq with multi APIs, but Sidekiq server executed wrong API code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, redis, sidekiq

I've built a rails app with docker-compose like below.

For example,
API A created job A1, that pushed to redis by Sidekiq Client SA.

And API B created job B1, that pushed to redis by Sidekiq Client SB.

But when these jobs executed, It pointed to application code in only API A.
So job B1 was failed because it was executed by API A.

I know that because the uninitialized constant error was raised.

I also used redis-namespace, but it still pointed to wrong API.

Can you help me explain how Sidekiq Server executed jobs.
And how it point to the right API that the job belongs to.

Many thanks.

```
config_redis = {
  url: ENV.fetch('REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ', 'redis://localhost:6379/0'),
  namespace: ENV.fetch('REDIS_NAMESPACE_SIDEKIQ', 'super_admin')
}

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = config_redis
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = config_redis
end
```

initializer/sidekiq.rb

```
config_redis = {
  url: ENV.fetch('REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ', 'redis://localhost:6379/0'),
  namespace: ENV.fetch('REDIS_NAMESPACE_SIDEKIQ', 'ignite')
}

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = config_redis
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = config_redis
end
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  ccp-ignite-api-gmv: # ----------- IGNITE SERVER
    build: ../ccp-ignite-api-gmv/.
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint.sh
    command: WEB 3001
    # command: MIGRATE # Uncomment this if you want to run db:migrate only
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
      - ../ccp-ignite-api-gmv/.:/src
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    links:
      - db
      - redis
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: ${RAILS_ENV}
      REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ: redis://redis:6379/ignite
      REDIS_NAMESPACE_SIDEKIQ: ignite
  ccp-super-admin-api-gmv: # ----------- SUPER ADMIN API SERVER
    build: ../ccp-super-admin-api-gmv/.
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint.sh
    command: WEB 3005
    # command: MIGRATE # Uncomment this if you want to run db:migrate only
    ports:
      - "3005:3005"
    volumes:
      - ../ccp-super-admin-api-gmv/.:/src
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    links:
      - db
      - redis
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: ${RAILS_ENV}
      REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ: redis://redis:6379/super_admin
      REDIS_NAMESPACE_SIDEKIQ: super_admin
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.22
    volumes:
      - ~/docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
  redis:
    image: redis:5-alpine
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - ~/docker/redis:/data
  sidekiq_ignite:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ=redis://redis:6379/0
      - REDIS_NAMESPACE_SIDEKIQ=ignite
  sidekiq_super_admin:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ=redis://redis:6379/0
      - REDIS_NAMESPACE_SIDEKIQ=super_admin
```

Comment: I've found the issue.
My config for service sidekiq at volume and build was wrong.

Comment: if you found the issue, it would be helpful if you could share in an answer what the problem was and mark your answer as the accepted answer in case someone has the some config problem

Answer (score 1):

Thanks st.huber for reminding me,

That confused came from my wrong docker-compose config in 2 sidekiq service.
I've pointed to wrong folder in "build" and "command"

Before:

```
sidekiq_ignite:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ=redis://redis:6379/0
      - REDIS_NAMESPACE_SIDEKIQ=ignite
  sidekiq_super_admin:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ=redis://redis:6379/0
      - REDIS_NAMESPACE_SIDEKIQ=super_admin
```

Fixed:

```
sidekiq_ignite:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    build: ../ccp-ignite-api-gmv/.
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    volumes:
      - ../ccp-ignite-api-gmv/.:/src
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ=redis://redis:6379/0
      - REDIS_NAMESPACE_SIDEKIQ=ignite
  sidekiq_super_admin:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    build: ../ccp-super-admin-api-gmv/.
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    volumes:
      - ../ccp-super-admin-api-gmv/.:/src
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ=redis://redis:6379/0
      - REDIS_NAMESPACE_SIDEKIQ=super_admin
```